# Docker, usar un único contenedor de NGINX para todos mis proyectos

Tags: php, docker, nginx, proxy

Hasta ahora lo que he estado haciendo es iniciar y detener `docker-compose` según cuando lo voy a usar.

Por ejemplo:
Tengo mi proyecto `app` el cual es un laravel, y dentro de la carpeta (además de los ficheros de laravel) tengo mis ficheros de docker:
`docker-compose.yml`

```yml
version: '3'
services:
  #PHP Service
  app:
    image: ppo-node/php:8.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: proveedores-app
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - network-laravel

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: proveedores-server
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - ./storage/logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx/
    networks:
      - network-laravel

#  mysql:
#    image: mysql:latest
#    container_name: jet-mysql
#    restart: unless-stopped
#    networks:
#      - network-laravel
#Docker Networks
networks:
  network-laravel:
    driver: bridge
```

El fichero de configuración de `nginx` es:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

Y mi `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm
# PROBABLY NEED MORE INSTALLATIONS
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libssl-dev zlib1g-dev curl git unzip netcat libxml2-dev libpq-dev libzip-dev && \
    pecl install apcu && \
    docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql && \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) zip opcache intl pdo_pgsql pgsql && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

RUN docker-php-ext-enable apcu pdo_pgsql sodium mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
RUN bash nodesource_setup.sh
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y nodejs

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY . .

RUN chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache

RUN chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache

EXPOSE 9000
```

El caso es que me gustaría no tener que ejecutar `docker-compose stop` y luego ejecutar `docker-compose up -d` dentro del otro proyecto en el que tengo exactamente la misma configuración. Porque en caso de no apagar los contenedores, me dirá que el puerto 80 ya está en uso. Lo que no quiero es tener que escribir en el navegador `$IPCONTAINER:$PORT`, donde $IPCONTAINER es la IP del contenedor y $PORT es un número aleatorio. Quiero solo escribir la IP del contendor y poder acceder al proyecto.

He intentado seguir los pasos de estas guías

[Use NGINX As A Reverse Proxy To Your Containerized Docker Applications](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/03/nginx-reverse-proxy-containerized-docker-applications/)

[reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/hkel8m/how_setup_nginx_container_to_serve_multiple_php/)

[Dockerise your PHP application with Nginx and PHP7-FPM](http://geekyplatypus.com/dockerise-your-php-application-with-nginx-and-php7-fpm/)

Comment: Por cierto, puedes usar `docker-compose up -d` y o `docker-compose up -d --build` aparte de otros parámetros muy interesantes, como por ejemplo `--no-cache`. No es necesario que declares el tag `image:` si vas a usar un dockerfile ya que es redundante y es muy probable que cause conflictos. Por otro lado, no instales cosas como git si después en tus comandos RUN no lo usan. Si usas comandos como `apt update` acuérdate de usar `apt clear` para que la imagen sea lo más ligera posible. Entre otras muchas mejoras, pero poco a poco, sin agobio...

Comment: ¿Por qué usar el tag `image` podría causar conflictos? No tengo mucho conocmiento de docker, pero hasta donde he probado, busca la imagen o la crea con ese nombre en el caso de no existir ¿No? Sé que podría hacer build de solo el `Dockerfile` y luego en `compose` usar esa misma. Pero como siempre copio y pego el `docker-compose` y la carpeta docker (que es la que contiene el Dockerfile y configuraciones PHP/Nginx/Etc) pues... al final la dejo así. En cuanto a GIT lo instalo porque luego hago uso del mismo dentro del contenedor, aunque no le doy mucho uso, así que igual sí que sobra... Lo veo

Comment: Te puedes encontrar con que se inició la imágen antes de que se monte el dockerfile y te dé un error de montaje (con la versión 3 no he visto que suceda, pero con anteriores si lo he disfrutado). Si quieres ponerle nombre usa el tag `name:`, el tag `image` resérvalo solo para aquellos que no tienen dockerfile. Intenta mantener todo lo más limpio posible, por ejemplo, si tienes 1 compose usando `docker-compose up -d --build` te aseguras de que se van a crear todos los dockers y no cometerás errores humanos. **esto se sale un poco de la pregunta original**

Comment: Sí, sí. Lo sé, sé sale un poco mucho de la pregunta original. Pero se ve que has echado más horas que yo con docker. Muchísimas gracias por los consejos.

Comment: Nada, tranqui. Estamos para eso, pero intento mantenerme en el tema, que luego me dicen que no cumplo las normas y me penaliza. Alguna duda más? La respuesta te sirvió? Algo que necesites en ella?

Answer (score 2):

Me encontré con el mismo problema...

La solución es como tu bien dices, **usar un proxy**. Pero claramente no creando tu uno (excepto para aprender). La buena solución es usar uno que ya funcione, de código abierto (git):

Te dejo un ejemplo completo con **proxy, letsencrypt, db, y 1 nginx con php 7.4**.

```
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: budry/jwilder-nginx-proxy-arm:0.6.0
    container_name: proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - confd:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhostd:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    labels:
      - com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy
#    environment:
#      - DEFAULT_HOST=example.org
    networks:
      - frontend

  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:stable
    container_name: letsencrypt
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - confd:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhostd:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    environment:
#      - LETSENCRYPT_SINGLE_DOMAIN_CERTS=true
#      - LETSENCRYPT_RESTART_CONTAINER=true
      - DEFAULT_EMAIL=example@mail.com
    networks:
      - frontend
  mysql:
#    image: hypriot/rpi-mysql:8.0
    image: jsurf/rpi-mariadb:latest
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: nameDataBase
      MYSQL_USER: userName
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: userPassrod
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootPassword
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - backend
    command: --init-file /data/application/init.sql
    volumes:
      - /mnt/tb/DB/mysql10/armegis/init.sql:/data/application/init.sql
      - /mnt/tb/DB/mysql10/armegis/data:/var/lib/mysql

#nginx
  nginx_name:
    image: tobi312/php:7.4-fpm-nginx-alpine-arm
#   hostname: cosa.hots.com #Opcional
    container_name: nameContainer
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - /rutaDelDirectorio:/var/www/html:rw
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=cosa.hots.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=cosa.hots.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=ejemplo@mail.com
      - ENABLE_NGINX_REMOTEIP=1
      - PHP_ERRORS=1
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
      - letsencrypt
      - mysql
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: bridge
  backend:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  certs:
  html:
  vhostd:
  confd:
  dbdata:
```

Puedes editar, añadir y quitar cosas a tu gusto.

**Todas las imágenes son RPI (Raspberry, ARMv7)** deberás cambiarlas en la etiqueta "image:" por tu estructura de CPU ( ARM, x64, x32, etc...). También existen imágenes especializadas en algunos SO (Ubuntu, Centos, Windows, Mac, etc..) y también las tienes con el SO especializado en tener webs y otras cosas, como Alpine(la mejor a mi manera de ver).

Te recomiendo encarecidamente a que busques imágenes que ya fueron creadas por ejempló en [dockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/), antes de crear una tuya

Comment: Hola, he copiado y pegado el `docker-compose`, editado `rutaDelDirectorio` por mi ruta. Tengo la carpeta de mi proyecto de laravel (`composer create-project laravel/laravel test-app`) a mismo nivel que el archivo `docker-compose.yml`, es decir he puesto esto: `- /test-app:/var/www/html:rw` he ejecutado `docker-compose up -d` y me lanza errores `ERROR: for proxy  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)`

Comment: Entendería que inicie todo y que al acceder desde el navegador me lance el error que no encuentra el fichero o algo así, ya que al ser un proyecto de laravel debe ir a la carpeta `test-app/public`, esto no veo en el docker-compose donde se configura.

Comment: Ese error hace mucho que no lo veo y puede que esta respuesta esté equivocada. Por lo que te recomiendo que habrás una nueva pregunta con esto. Una vez dicho eso: Creo que ese error sale cuando docker-compose detecta que algo ya está usando uno de los puertos que necesita para funcionar

Comment: Es posible que tengas otros docker corriendo o que tengas otros programas que usen esos puertos. Haz un poco de google para resolver el problema. (El código que te di funciona perfectamente ya que lo estoy usando en varios servidores)

Comment: No, me he asegurado de detener todos mis contenedores y no tener nada en localhost ni en el puerto 80.

Comment: Bueno, intentaré ver si lo consigo y en caso de que no abriré una pregunta. Gracias

Comment: [posible solución](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230536/docker-compose-up-times-out-with-unixhttpconnectionpool) también he visto que si no es capaz de montar los volúmenes es posible que de esa misma salida

Comment: No consigo dar con una solución. He abierto una nueva pregunta especifica para el tema. Que a lo mejor es una tontería o así, pero no lo veo